# Define dependent association model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, model

I have 2 models, `Article` and `Tag`.

I'm looking for a solution that when `Article` get deleted, All `tags` associated with deleted `article` get destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`ForeignKey`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) model field on your `Tag` model to point to your `Article` model.

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

If you delete an instance of `Article`, all dependent `Tag` instances will be deleted.

Comment: so, django naturally know it.., that's great. tnx